# Unable to add Native activity application on my create a project page in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android

I am unable to add native activity application on my create a project page in Visual Studio 2022.

I tried installing NDK (side by side) in Android Studio Giraffe and its showing as installed only
[Attached NDK.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnpZs.png)But still when selecting New Project, Native - Activity Application (Android), option is not coming for me even though while installing Mobile development with C++ was given. [Attached VisualStudio.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSMNF.png).
Please help to proceed further

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.